# mssql create view that joins table to itself

Tags: sql-server, self-join

I have a table as below:

```
itemid      details      color

t001        door         red

t002        gate         green

t002        gate         blue
```

I want to combine items with multiple colors / itemid onto one line. there will never be more than two colors

so desired output:

```
itemid      details      color1     color2

t001        door         red

t002        gate         green      blue
```

I have tried to do a join onto itself using a nested select and top 1 bottom 1 but does not work correctly

```
select itemid,t1.color,t2.color
from table1 t1 
join (
select top 1 color
from table1 where iteid=t1,itemid
) t2
```

any advice welcome,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but this could be an approach for you:

```
Select      a.itemid,
            a.details,
            a.color1,
            a.color2
from        (           
            Select      itemid,
                        details,
                        color as color1,
                        (Select color from #table1 as b where b.itemid = a.itemid and b.color <> a.color)   as color2
                        , ROW_NUMBER()   OVER (PARTITION BY itemid ORDER BY details DESC)  rn
            from        #table1     as a
            ) as a
where       a.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is group_concat().It helps to display multiple values separated by commas.You can also change the comma separator to anything you desire like | by giving a separator keyword.Ex:

> GROUP_CONCAT(color SEPARATOR '|')

```
select itemid,details,group_concat(color) 
from t1 group by itemid
```

Check this for output [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b281/1).Hope it helps.